# convert a character value to integer value

Tags: c

here when ever i find 'h' i have to access the values between p and h i.e 123 and i want that has int and store it in value as 123 itself how can i do this can any one tell me the logic, that code that i have written is not working and how to copy the values when the pointer is getting incremented

```
    main()
        {
            char *ptr1 = "p123h12";
            int value;
            while(*ptr1!= '\0')
            {
                if(*ptr1 == 'h')
                {
                value = (int)atoi(ptr1);
                printf("%d\n", value);
                }
            ptr1++;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

With [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/):

```
int value;
sscanf (ptr1,"p%dh12",&value);
```

**Update**

```
int i,j;
int values[MAX_VALUES];
int startIdx = -1;
char *ptr1 = "p123hxxxxp124hxxxxp123145hxxxx";
char buffer[16];
for(i=0,j=0; i<strlen(ptr1);i++)
{
    if(startIdx>=0 && ptr[i] == 'h')
    {
        strncpy(buffer,ptr1+startIdx,i-startIdx+1);
        buffer[i-startIdx+1]='\0';
        sscanf (buffer,"p%dh",&(values[j++]));
        startIdx = -1;
    }
    else if(ptr[i] == 'p')
    {
        startIdx = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: i cant use sscanf, i have to generalize it as i may get a input as p1hp123h.every time i have to take values between p and h...so have to use while loops and some conditions

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good possible starting point:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (void) {
    char *p, *str = "p123h12p97h62p32h";
    int accum = 0;

    // Process every character.

    for (p = str; *p != '\0'; p++) {
        // 'p' resets the accumulator.
        // 'h' outputs the accumulator.
        // Any digit adjusts the accumulator.

        if (*p == 'p')       accum = 0;
        if (*p == 'h')       printf ("Processing %d\n", accum);
        if (isdigit (*p))    accum = accum * 10 + *p - '0';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This will work fine if your input string follows your specified format, outputting:

```
Processing 123
Processing 97
Processing 32
```

If there's the possibility that your input string is not so well formed, you'll need to add some defensive coding.